# Web Server Raspberry stucked after few commands

Tags: php, jquery, raspberry-pi, webserver

I'm using a raspberry as a web server (Apache2, php5 and mysql). Everything works smoothly but one thing:

I built a sort of a remote for controlling a showroom. Every button does a POST request to a php page that with a socket change something in some software in another pc in the showroom.

The only thing that doesn't work is the "watchout" button. It works 1 or 2 times and then I need to reboot the raspberry. 
The same php page in other pcs with windows works without problems.

However here is the post:

```
            data ={};
            data =  {'watchout' : cmd};
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:  ajaxurl,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    timeout: 999
                }); 
            setTimeout(function(){
                data ={};
                data =  {'watchout' : run};
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:  ajaxurl,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    timeout: 1000,
                }); 
            },3000);
```

Here the "ajaxurl" is a php file that read the post and sen the cmd and the run commands to watchout with this function:

```
function udp($out_port,$out_ip,$out_message) {
    //echo "<div>UDP</div>";


/*
    Simple php udp socket client
*/

//Reduce errors
error_reporting(~E_WARNING);

$server = $out_ip;
$port = $out_port;

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

//Communication loop
//while(1)
//{
    //Take some input to send
    //echo 'Enter a message to send : ';
    //$input = fgets(STDIN);
    $input = $out_message;

    echo 'send:"'.$input.'",to: '.$server.' at: '.$port;

    //Send the message to the server
    if( ! socket_sendto($sock, $input , strlen($input) , 0 , $server , $port))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    //Now receive reply from server and print it
    if(socket_recv ( $sock , $reply , 2045 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE)
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Reply : $reply";
//}


    exit;
}

//---------------------
//END UDP
//--------------------
```

I repeat myself. This code in windows works well! Any idea on what I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your apache error.log or syslog give you any pointers?

Comment: You say "It works 1 or 2 times and then I need to reboot the raspberry" - why do you need to reboot? Can you connect to the Pi after it fails & look for log messages? I see you have some logging statements (`echo`, `die`) in your PHP code - are you seeing those messages? what happens when the Raspberry Pi fails?

Comment: @paula Livingstone there are no errors...

Comment: @kryten I need to reboot the raspberry because I can't connect to the server by browser anymore after it fails. I can look for log messages but there are no error messages.
If I refresh my page it load forever but nothing happens but when I shut down the raspberry it shows the error "page not found"...

In the network tab of the console of chrome, every request is timed out and canceled.